# writing a function that returns the highest roll of dice

Tags: javascript

this function should return the highest rolled number
in the given dice array ex: [2,3,5,1,2] -> 5

I have a function that should be linked to my new function but cannot remember what or where in the function I started I should link them.

```js
rollDie: function rollDie() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    }

   
    rollNDice: function rollNDice(n) {
        var result = [ ];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      result.push(rollDie()); 
  }                          
  return result;               
}
console.log(rollNDice(4));
```

This is my original code that I have to link with the new code I started.

```js
function maxRoll(arr){
var largest_num = [ ];
for(var i=0; i > arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i] < largest_num){
     largest_num = arr[i];
   }
}
return largest_num;
}
```

My new code where I need to link my original code in somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean "link them"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate or 'call' ? I'm not sure what the exact term is. But like how I called rollDie inside  rollNDice. I couldn't get it to work doing it the same way as before.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be calling the function that generates the rolls inside the function that figures out what the highest number is. Generate the numbers outside of the function, put them in a list, then pass it into the function. Functions should do as little as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `Math.max` function to find the largest number in an array:

```js
const rolls = [4, 7, 3, 2, 9, 5];
const maxRoll = Math.max(...rolls);

console.log(maxRoll);
```

The issue with your implementation is you have an infinite loop because you're checking if `i` is greater than `length` rather than less than `length`:

```
for(var i=0; i > arr.length; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Also your greater than check is flipped:

```
arr[i] < largest_num
```

Should be:

```
arr[i] > largest_num
```